# Problem using double quotes as commandline argument in C++

Tags: c++, terminal, parameters, double-quotes

I'm trying to do a program that detects '-m' as argument for a message and use double quotes between the message itself. Now I'm just trying to detect if the message starts with double quotes, but I get an unexpected behavior.

The main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc < 3){
        std::cerr << "Error! Bad usage of parameters" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++){
        std::string arg = argv[i];
        std::string nextarg = argv[i+1];
        if(arg == "-m"){ 
            if(nextarg.empty() || nextarg[0] != '"'){
                std::cout << "nextarg[0]: " << nextarg[0] << std::endl; 
                std::cout << "arg: " << arg << std::endl;
                std::cerr << "Error, message must be on double quotes" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "The code worked" << std::endl;
                std::cout << nextarg << std::endl;
                std::cout << arg << std::endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            std::cerr << "The value is invalid." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the input I'm using is `./compiled -m "foo foo"`, and the expected output is:

```
The code worked
"foo foo"
-m
```

But the actual output is:

```
nextarg[0]: f
arg: -m
Error, message must be on double quotes
```

So, I see the problem is probably that my program doesn't detect the first double quotes. Also, if I use only one double quotes, the output makes an infinite loop of '>' asking me for an input, I don't want that behavior in my program.

By the way, I don't know why but my program works if I use this input: `./compiled -m "\"foo foo\""`, so I think that must be a problem with the terminal itself, but I still don't know anything about that.

Comment: Yes the terminal is removing the quotes before your program even sees them.

Comment: This is a common behavior. On Linux shells do it automatically, on Windows the code that does usually gets automatically embedded into your apps (I think?). In any case, this is not a bad thing. It lets you use single words as messages without quotes, without having to handle it in the code.

Comment: Looks like you're running on Windows? If you do `.\compiled -m '"foo foo"'` then your program may see `"foo foo"` as a single argument with the double quotes intact. In Git Bash for Windows that's how I would expect it to work at least. Otherwise, the quotes get removed first at the command-line and you get `foo foo` as the single argument, without the quotes.

Comment: Start debugging by just iterating through the `argv` array of strings, printing out each argument on a separate line. Then, practice passing it different arguments with different quoting patterns to see the results your program is seeing, so you can know how to parse it from there.

Comment: Dont guess what your code does. Use a debugger. The first thing you want to inspect is what `arg` and `nextarg` really are.  [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @GabrielStaples No, I'm running on Linux, specifically in Arch Linux using Bash.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6b9P3n1d6

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I will keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: Can you use third party libraries? There are nice tools which can parse program arguments. There is no point to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MarekR I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I want to comprehend how it works. But I will keep it in mind for future uses, thanks.

Comment: In that case, there's a typo in your question. Since you used `.\ ` instead of `./` I thought you were on Windows. `.\compiled -m "foo foo"` should be `./compiled -m "foo foo"`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: This is not an issue with your code, but rather a matter of how the operating system processes command line arguments.  In that sense it is off-topic.  The shell uses space as an argument delimiter, so arguments that contain spaces must be enclosed in quotes to be considered a single argument, they are not however part of the argument.  To include a `"` _anywhere_ in an argument string, you need to use the escape sequence `\"`.  Other operating systems or command shells may vary, and other methods may be supported.

Comment: @Clifford, if you make that an answer, I'll upvote it. This will certainly help others. That's the main goal here: create a canonical repository of useful programming information to refer to. Making an answer around your comment would do that.

Comment: @GabrielStaples As I said, I do not regard this as a programming issue, so off topic.  The syntax and semantics of the command line apply to any executable. One for https://superuser.com/